# SSH connection only blocked from LAN

Tags: networking, ssh

I've been fighting this problem for quite a long time, and am almost out of ideas. First of all, a [link](http://pastebin.com/kK12zeLD) to my shell output where I tried to show as much info as possible in each case.

I have a centos 7.2 server at home, the router redirects port 2222 to the server's 22. Whenever I ssh to the router's public ip (both fom my LAN and from an outside connection), all is good, I manage to get a connection to my box.

If I connect to my server from outside my LAN with the help of openVPN, I manage to get an ssh connection afterwards even when I'm in another subnet.

But, if I try to connect directly from my house's wifi, boom no connection, it simply hangs. I simply have no idea how this is even possible. And google-fu returns results with the opposite problem. I hope the logs provided can at least serve to make my explanation clearer (disregard the host autenticity warnings, the connexion attempts did not happen in the order on the pastebin)

No other computer on the LAN can SSH the server, all will return the same output. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please give some more detailed Information: Which port do you ssh to when using WiFi? 22 or 2222? And which IP address, the local one or the public one of the router?

Comment: sounds like Wifi Client Isolation. This feature prevents wireless clients from connecting to other systems on the LAN. Its designed to prevent one user in a coffee shop from attacking other users in that shop, or accessing the shops LAN systems.  I am actually suprised that your router supports hairpin NAT, such that you can connect to the public address from within your LAN.

Comment: @Jounathaen Please consult the pastebin provided, both your questions are answered there (<redacted public ip> means something like 83.55.222.14)

Comment: @Frank Thomas Thanks, will look into it and update my question either with new info or with a soution.

Answer (score 2):

This is typical when using the public IP from the internal network.

Some assumptions for the example:

- Public IP `1.2.3.4`
- Router internal IP `192.168.1.1`
- CentOS server IP `192.168.1.100`

Then we have:

- If you are on the wild internet, you should SSH to `1.2.3.4:2222` which the router will route to `192.168.1.100:22`.
- If you are on your intranet (at home with WiFi), you should use `192.168.1.100:22` directly since the router will not translate ports or external IPs here.

Comment: Thanks but I already knew that, please check the link I provided and you'll be able to see that I SSH'd from the lan to the local ip @ port 22 (bar the made up ip, I did what you sugested)

Comment: Please just put your diagnostic output inline in your post. Many folks here won't check out posted links due to security concerns.